# What means "ambient" in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I don't understand what means the word `ambient` in the following sentence:

> A function implementation cannot be declared in an ambient context.

I'm not sure to understand the general meaning of the word, *(English isn't my maternal language)* and if there is a specific meaning here I don't get it as well.

I've tried to understand in my maternal language but couldn't get it in this context. It's something like `current context` I'd say but it doesn't work out.

The message appeared because I was trying to `declare` a class, which cannot be declared, only `module` can. I've fixed it but still don't understand the meaning of the error message here.

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf

Comment: The link is not working any more

Comment: Chapter "Ambient Modules" in (here)[https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html] is the corresponding I think

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ambient simply means ["without implementation"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/issues/180#issuecomment-195452691).

Ambient declarations only exist in the type system and are erased at run-time:

```
// ambient module declaration
declare module "mymod" { /*... */ }

// ambient namespace declaration
declare namespace MyNamespace { /*... */ }

// ambient variable declaration
declare const myVar: string;
```

For example `declare const myVar: string` is like a promise to the compiler: "Assume that there will be a `const myVar` with type `string` defined at *run-time*" (other cases analogue).

You also can think of ambient as the [`declare`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#11-ambient-declarations) keyword in TS. All type declarations like [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) or [type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) are implicitly ambient by definition, as it is clear for the compiler, that these have no run-time impact.

```
declare type MyType = {a: string} // is valid
type MyType = {a: string} // shorter, so just leave "declare" out
```

---

> "A function implementation cannot be declared in an ambient context."

As said, ambient declarations cannot contain run-time code, like:

```
declare module "mymod" {
    function foo() { // error: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.
        console.log("bar")
    }
}
```

Given `"mymod"` is a npm package, the implementation code would rather be in the main `.js` file under `"node_modules/mymod"`, and above types reside in a separate `.d.ts` file.

Comment: By far, the most comprehensive answer I've seen on this topic. I actually understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

## The english word

Ambience : `the character and atmosphere of a place.`.

## TypeScript version

TypeScript declaration files exist to tell the compiler of the environment in which it is running. Hence the word *ambient context*. You can only do *declarations* in a declaration context and not *implementations*.

E.g. if you have some `awesomeLibrary` declared in a raw JS file that TypeScript does not know about the following will error:

```
awesomeLibrary = 123; // Error: `awesomeLibrary` is not defined
```

So you can declare it in an ambient context and now TypeScript will be fine:

```
declare var awesomeLibrary: any;
awesomeLibrary = 123; // allowed
```

## More

[More on ambient declarations](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/intro.html).

Comment: So the short of it is that you can't declare anything but an interface in a .d.ts file.

Comment: No. There are other declarations e.g. `declare var foo:number;` that are not interfaces. You cannot however do `declare var foo = 123` as you are trying to assign `foo` to `123` ... that is an Implementation.

Comment: I get what ambient means in the real world.  But what makes something ambient in TypeScript?

Comment: In my case, I'm defining interfaces and classes in the d.ts, my classes where supossed to be free of implementation and I was getting that error, after reviewing I realized I still got the constructor implementation for each class. I think a more "developer friendly description" would be welcome, something like "a definition class cannot contain implementation, please review you don't have any constructor or functions implemented", and some link explaining how this work and common pitfalls.

Comment: This isn't even an answer, and the link provided doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

✅ Ambient declarations are useful when integrating TypeScript with existing JavaScript libraries.

✅ Allowing TypeScript to perform type checking.

✅ Typically declared using the "declare" keyword and are placed in declaration files (".d.ts")
or within TypeScript files while using "declare module" syntax.

Example:

Consider you're using an external JavaScript library named "formatter.js" that provides a global "formatString" function. However, this library doesn't have TypeScript type definitions.

You can create an ambient declaration: To inform TypeScript about this function's existence and type.

```
// Create a declaration file (formatter.d.ts)

declare function formatString(value:string): string
```