# Does a module make typescript code "Ambient"

Tags: typescript

I am trying to get started with some typescript.  This is what I looks like:

```
declare module ServiceActions {
    export class MyClass{
        myFunction(shipmentId: number) : void {
            let test: number;
            test = 32;
        }
    }
}
```

When I do that I get this error:

> An Implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.

When I take out the module, it works fine:

```
export class MyClass{
    myFunction(shipmentId: number) : void {
        let test: number;
        test = 32;
    }
}
```

I thought I read that Modules are like namespaces in Typescript, but this seems to make it more like an abstract/interface concept.

**Am I really getting this error because of the module?  If not, why am I gettin this error?**

Note: I saw this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946495/what-means-ambient-in-typescript) and it did not answer my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, you are in an "ambient" context because of the `declare` keyword. What you want here is to use `export` on your module:

```
export module ServiceActions {
    export class MyClass{
        myFunction(shipmentId: number) : void {
            let test: number;
            test = 32;
        }
    }
}
```

You could also just leave off the `export` altogether, which would be more like a namespace declaration. `export` is needed if you're using something like AMD or CommonJS or ES2015 for module declarations.

`declare` is used when you want to specify a module to contain things like interfaces. So perhaps:

```
declare module ServiceActions {
    interface MyInterface {
        myFunction(shipmentId: number) : void;
    }
}
module ServiceActions {
    export class MyClass implements MyInterface {
        myFunction(shipmentId: number) : void {
            let test: number;
            test = 32;
        }
    }
}
```

You'll see it a lot in `.d.ts` files, for example.