# Trying to declare a function, getting error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient

Tags: typescript

I am declaring a function say getValue.  Then I am defining this getValue.  But I am getting error as

`error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient`.

What does ambient overload signature mean? What does non-ambient signature mean?  How do I define a declared function without getting this error?

```
declare function getValue(key:string):any;

function getValue(key:string):any{
    return key;
}
```

Comment: Just remove `declare` keyword

Comment: that is a quick fix but please tell me why cant i define a declared function

Comment: Related: [What does “ambient” mean in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946495/what-means-ambient-in-typescript)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`declare` means that you don't ever intend to provide a value for that variable. It says to the compiler:

> "I know this value doesn't exist in the code you can see, but I promise you that it's defined somewhere that is available to this scope, and this is its type"

So there would be no need for `declare` if you also provide a concrete value. Either `declare` the function, meaning it is defined somewhere the typescript compiler can't see, or remove the declare line altogether and export the function itself for use wherever you want.

(Secondarily, `declare` is useful for academic explorations of the type system. You can `declare` a variable with with a type, without ever providing a value for it, and then inspect the types downstream where that variable is used. This usage is ***absolutely not intended for production code.***)

---

> What does ambient overload signature mean?

"ambient" means no implementation exists. This is triggered by the `declare` keyword. [Overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) signatures happen when you write the a function type multiple times, with different argument types/return types. By having the function mentioned on two lines, typescript interprets that as a function overload.

> What does non-ambient signature mean?

It means that an implementation could exist for this function.

> How do I define a declared function without getting this error?

You don't. If you want to write an implementation for a function, do not use the `declare` keyword for that functions type.

Comment: I wonder why declare is not documented more like this in typescript docs

Comment: I wan't able to find any docs on this myself, sadly. But this is how it works. Another example of how declare works: https://tsplay.dev/OwEEkw Note how `getValue()` is never implemented, yet typescript is happy.

Answer (score 4):

"Ambient" is a declaration that does not define an implementation (e.g. with the `declare` keyword). See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html. The point of ambient type definitions is to define types that come from third party libraries that don't have types or that may exist in the global space. I'm actually not sure of all the details of why you're not allowed to mix ambient and non-ambient declarations, but one may be that you are accidentally overloading an existing third party function that has an ambient definition.

You can define function overloads without `declare`, but they can still have only one implementation:

```
// note that this doesn't actually overload anything yet
function getValue(key:string):any;
function getValue(key:string):any{
  return key;
}
```

Comment: how am i accidentally overloading an existing third party function that has an ambient definition.here .I dint get this @Explosion Pills

Comment: @somanraj I'm not saying that you are doing this, I'm just saying that if you had done this, you would also get this error. That is one of the things this error protects against.

Comment: @Explosin Pills Thanks now i got it

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for those who came to this page by searching for the mentioned error:
For my case it was a function called "print" . Rename this may work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The answers stating that you should not declare functions that you are going to define in the code are correct (since declaration means that you will be importing some library that will define that function and you should not load declarations of your current code), but I had a complex setup where I was using a shared library in two different places. In one of the places I wanted to override the default implementation of the function with another one. To overcome this error in such case you can reassign the value of the function instead of redefining it (tested with TypeScript 4.8.4):

```ts
getValue = (key:string):any => {
    return key;
}
```