# crypto-pouch showing import error in angular

Tags: angular, pouchdb, crypto-pouch

I have imported crypto pouch in angular like below

```
import CryptoPouch from 'crypto-pouch';
```

But its showing error like below,

Could not find a declaration file for module 'crypto-pouch'. '/home/excercise_task/pouchDB/pouchApp/node_modules/crypto-pouch/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/crypto-pouch` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'crypto-pouch';`ts(7016)

Comment: This is not an uncommon issue with TypeScript. As the compiler hints, this problem exists because there is no [ambient declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946495/what-means-ambient-in-typescript) for that module, e.g. crypto-pouch.d.ts.

There are a lot of workarounds.  The professional way is the hero route: define the typings of crypto-pouch and submit that as a PR to the [crypto-pouch github project](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/crypto-pouch).  Otherwise search the web for `ts(7016)` for a suitable solution - there is no definitive answer other than providing a .d.ts.

Answer (score 0):

Change import statement to require:

```
const CryptoPouch = require('crypto-pouch');
```

If you get could not find name ***require*** like the message below:

> Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions
> for node?

Run:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/node
```

Comment: No its not working

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
I ended up writing the type definition for crypto-pouch which merged at DefinitelyTyped, so just do this

```bash
$ npm install --save-dev @types/crypto-pouch
```

and don't use the work-around below

---

With respect to my comment on the OP, since [crypto-pouch](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/crypto-pouch) only has two methods, and I've never written a pouchy plugin declaration, here's this.  Just copy this content and place in your project, e.g. `src\crypto-pouch.d.ts` for an angular project.  Intellisense should pickup this up and the ts(7016) should evaporate.

```ts
// extend PouchDB for the crypto-pouch plugin 

declare module "crypto-pouch"; // define the module for this definition

declare namespace PouchDB {
    namespace CryptoPouch {
        type Options = {
            /* A string password, used to encrypt documents. */
            password: string;
            /* (optional) Array of strings of properties that will not be encrypted. */
            ignore?: string[];
        };
    }
    /* Plugin */
    interface Database<Content extends {} = {}> {
        /**
         *
         * @param options See CryptoPouch.Options
         */
        crypto(options: CryptoPouch.Options): Promise<void>;
        /**
         *
         * @param password A string password, used to encrypt documents.
         * @param ignore Array of strings of properties that will not be encrypted.
         */
        crypto(password: string, ignore?: string[]): Promise<void>;
        /**
         * Disables encryption on the database and forgets your password.
         */
        removeCrypto(): void;
    }
}
```