# function with return statement moved to index.d.ts throws build Error TS1036 ... _worked perfectly in a regular TS file before_

Tags: typescript, rxjs, typescript-typings, stenciljs, stencil-component

Node v14.x, StencilJS (React) v2.3.x

I had a **test-helper** file with an exported function that converts string-arrays to number-arrays:

```js
export function parseNumericStringOrStringArrayToIntegers(value: string | (string | string[])[]): number | (number | number[])[] {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return parseInt(value);
  } else {
    return value.map((item) => parseNumericStringOrStringArrayToIntegers(item)) as number | (number | number[])[];
  }
}
```

I decided that this function should be in `index.d.ts` of the component, so I could use it more logically in the component itself. I moved it and changed `export` to `declare`, removed `import {parseNumericStringOrStringArrayToIntegers} from "./index";` where it was altered by *JetBrains IDE > move*, and strangely expected stuff to '***just work***'. It didn't...

It threw me two errors in `npm run build` that seem relevant, but *I have no clue* how to fix it:

```
[ ERROR ]  TypeScript: ./src/components/app/index.d.ts:46:108
           An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.

     L46:  declare function parseNumericStringOrStringArrayToIntegers(value: string | (string | string[])[]): ConfigIntValue {
     L47:    if (typeof value === 'string') {

[ ERROR ]  TypeScript: ./src/components/app/index.d.ts:48:5
           Statements are not allowed in ambient contexts.

     L47:  if (typeof value === 'string') {
     L48:    return parseInt(value);
     L49:  } else {
```

Apparently, I'm missing something obvious here, but what?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946495/what-means-ambient-in-typescript  holds the answer to **why**, but I'm still in the blank on **how to fix it**.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here may be that you're placing the implementation in `index.d.ts`:

> I decided that this function should be in index.d.ts of the component

Files that end with `.d.ts` are [type declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/type-declarations.html), which are special files in TypeScript that cannot contain implementations of functions, only their type information. Without seeing the entire codebase, I suspect that this is the cause. If you move the code to `index.ts` or any other non-`.d.ts`, this may resolve your issue