# How to import an extended Array interface definition

Tags: typescript, typescript-module-resolution

In `src/types/array.d.ts` I extended the `Array` interface by defining:

```
export {}

declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    binaryIndexOf(e: T, desc: boolean): number
    addSorted(e: T, desc: boolean): T[]
  }
}

if (!Array.prototype.binaryIndexOf) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'binaryIndexOf', {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    configurable: false,
    value: function binaryIndexOf<T>(this: T[], e: T, desc: boolean) {
...
```

But I'm not able to import the new definition as when I run the code I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module './types/array'
```

My attempts:

```
import './types/array'
import {} from './types/array'
```

Here is the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  }
}
```

How can I import and use the extended `Array` interface properly?

Comment: Place your global augmentation in a separate file (while making sure it's still included in the project) and remove all static exports and imports. Then you don't need to import it because it's in an [ambient context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946495/what-means-ambient-in-typescript).

Comment: The global augmentation is in the `src/types/array.d.ts` file, what you mean by "included in the project"?

Comment: You should only have the *types* in that file. You implement the extension somewhere else. Remove all static export and import statements from the file.

Comment: For "extension" do you mean the `Object.defineProperty`?

Comment: Yes whatever you do to make your augmentation a reality.