# Typescript augmenting/monkey-patching a new attribute for Konva classes

Tags: typescript, konvajs, konva

I am new to typescript and having trouble to monkey-patch a new attribute '_model' referring to my data-model with one of the classes of the [Konva](https://konvajs.org/) library.

The idea is to have the model available during the mouse interaction events and be able to modify it based on the changes. Therefore I'm trying to augment the Konva primitives with a '_model' attribute
e.g. file *test.d.ts*:

```
import { Konva } from 'konva';

interface JsonModel {
    x: number
    y: number
    radius: number
}

declare module "konva" {

    namespace Konva {
        interface Circle {
            _model: JsonModel
        }
    }
}
```

file *test.ts*:

```
import Konva from "konva";

let circle = new Konva.Circle()
circle._model = {x:100, y:100, radius: 20}    
//     ^^^^^^
```

I get a compile error "Property '_model' does not exist on type 'Circle'", maybe this has something to do with the namespace not being imported correctly so the attribute is augmented with the wrong class?
Thanks in advance for any help on this

Comment: Static imports and exports make the file a module and not an [ambient context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946495/what-means-ambient-in-typescript).

Comment: @caTS, I try to make it an ambient context by removing ´import { Konva } from 'konva';´ from test.d.ts but to no avail. Still the _model is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question. But instead of doing typescript magic, just write your data as a custom attribute. Typescript will understand it:

```js
import Konva from "konva";

let circle = new Konva.Circle()
circle.setAttr('_model', {x:100, y:100, radius: 20});
circle.getAttr('_model');
```